# If I omit "a" is the sentence still correct?

Tags: american-english

We decided to keep it **a** secret. Here, if i omit here "a", will the sentence still be correct?

And what's the necessity of "a" here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "a" can be omitted in this sentence and it means exactly the same thing. Technically "We decided to keep it a secret" is using "secret" as a noun and "We decided to keep it secret" is using "secret" as an adjective, but there's no difference in usage.

Comment: Thank you so much!